# Problemas para somar valores usando Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Veja o resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--inserindo a meta tag de keywords onde definimos as palavras chaves-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--descrição do nosso site-->
    <meta name="description" content="Sistema" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--inseri um logo para o meu sistema <!-https://www.iconfinder.com -->
    <link href="../Content/images/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Sistema</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- adicionado o css do carousel -->
    <link href="~/Content/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>



<script>
    angular.module("ListaDados", []);
    angular.module("ListaDados").controller("ListaDadosCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.app = "Dados que serão inseridos";

        $scope.numeros = [];
        $scope.total = 0;

        $scope.adicionar = function (numero) {
            $scope.numeros.push(angular.copy(numero));
            $scope.total += parseFloat(numero.valor);
            $scope.total = toFixed($scope.total);
            delete $scope.numero; //aqui eu limpo os campos dos inputs apos adicionar
        };

        $scope.apagar = function (numeros) {
            $scope.numeros = numeros.filter(function (numero) {
                if (!numero.selecionado) return numero;
            });
        };


        $scope.isNumeroSelecionado = function (numeros) {
            return numeros.some(function(numero){
              return numero.selecionado;
            });
        };

        //função para subtrair os valores
        $scope.subtrairValores = function () {
            $scope.numeros.forEach(function (el, i) {
                if ($scope.numeros[i].selecionado) { $scope.total -= parseFloat($scope.numeros[i].valor); };
            })
            $scope.total = toFixed($scope.total);
        };

    });
</script>


<!-- formatar casas decimais-->
<script>
    function toFixed(number) {
        number = parseFloat(number);
        if (number % 1 != 0) {
            return parseFloat(number.toFixed(2));
        } else {
            return number;
        }
    }

</script>


</head>
```

No html

```html
<br />
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Vendedor: @Session["nome"]</small> </div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Jogo: @Session["descricao_modalidade"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Limite: @Session["limite_aceite"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Extração: @Session["descricao_estracao"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Fechamento: @Session["hora_fechamento"] - Dia: @Session["dia_da_semana"] </small></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><small> Valor Total:  {{total}}  </small></div>
 </div>


<table class="table table-bordered" ng-show="numeros.length > 0" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Número: </th>
            <th>Valor: </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-class="{'selecionado negrito':numero.selecionado}"  ng-repeat=" numero in numeros" >
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="numero.selecionado" /></td>
            <td>{{numero.nJogo}}</td>
            <td>{{numero.valor}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


@*<input class="form-control input-sm" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="valor" maxlength="5" type="text" ng-model="numero.valor" />*@

<div class="container droppedHover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <input class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="número" maxlength="4"  type="text"  ng-model="numero.nJogo" />
            <input class="form-control input-sm"  type="number" name="myDecimal" ng-change="somarValores()"  placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="numero.valor" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="adicionar(numero)" ng-disabled="!numero.nJogo || !numero.valor">Adicionar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block " ng-click="subtrairValores(); apagar(numeros)" ng-show="isNumeroSelecionado(numeros)" >Apagar</button>

</div>

<br />
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `+= parseFloat($scope.numero.valor)`?

Comment: @SamirBraga, sim, eu testei mais os valores sobrescrever, nao soma é também não subtrai

Comment: Após analisar seu código, possuo uma dúvia: o total, que você deseja, é a soma de todos os `valor` das tabela?

Comment: @SamirBraga, sim, eu estou  preenchendo o array manualmente, ai eu quero somar o total dos registros que foram adicionados ou reduzir se o mesmo for apagado

Comment: O problema, é que na sua função `somarValores()`, logo no início você declara o `$scope.valor = 0`, o que impede de se somar, já que sempre antes a da soma, o valor será 0.

Comment: @SamirBraga, seu eu comentar $scope.total = 0; não soma, será que consigo fazer isso com jquery?

Comment: Exatamente isso que extava percenbendo, na verdade ele transfroma o valor em NaN. Imagino que sim, um pouco mais trabalhoso, mas é possível. Estarei dando uma olhada em seu código, qualquer coisa aviso.

Comment: @SamirBraga, agradeço a sua colaboração em ajudar, fico muito grato por existir pessoas como você neste site que é sem dúvidas o melhor site para quem quer  apender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, como disse, dei uma olhada sem seu código e fiz algumas reformulações. Pelo menos aqui tá funcionando...

## Reformulações

### No Javascript

#### 1.

Retire o `delete $scope.numeros` da função `adicionar()`. Não sei o porquê de você ter posto isso aí, mas irá deletar o `numeros` após adicionar um valor a ele, então, para mim não fez sentido, assim como não é funcional. Ficará assim:

```
$scope.adicionar = function (numero) {
   $scope.numeros.push(angular.copy(numero));
};
```

#### 2.

Retirar o `$scope.total = 0` de dentro da função `somarValores()`, pois caso contrário a função sempre substituirá o valor e não o somará. E criei um `argument` "numero". Que terá que ser especificado no `ng-click` mais a frente. Outra coisa importante é retirar a condição:

```
if($scope.total == 0) $scope.total = "";
```

Porque com ela, você estará transformando o `total` em uma string e impossibilitando a aplicação de operações matemáticas sobre ele, posteriormente. O resultado ficaria simplesmente assim:

```
$scope.total = 0;
$scope.somarValores = function (numero) {
     $scope.total += parseFloat(numero);    
}
```

#### 3.

Criar a função `subtrairValores()`, que excluirá os valores deletados:

```
$scope.subtrairValores = function () {
    $scope.numeros.forEach(function(el, i) {
        if($scope.numeros[i].selecionado){  $scope.total -= parseFloat($scope.numeros[i].valor); };
    }) 
}
```

.

### No HTML

#### 1.

Retirar todos os `ng-change`, pois com eles quando você digitar o valor, a cada tecla o valor antigo irá ser somado com o novo valor (valor com o novo digito). Ou seja, se estava `5`, e você digo mais `1`, ele somou o `5 + 51`, ficando `56`.

#### 2.

Colocar a função `somarValores()` no botão "adicionar" ao invés de nos `ng-change`, sem esquecer de especifcar o argumento `numero.valor`, ficaria assim:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="adicionar(numero); somarValores(numero.valor)" ng-disabled="!numero.nJogo || !numero.valor">Adicionar</button>
```

#### 3.

Especificar o a função `subtrairValores()` no `ng-click` no botão apagar, porém antes da função `apagar()`, para que assim se possa subtrair os valores antes que os mesmos sejam deletados.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block " ng-click="subtrairValores(); apagar(numeros)" ng-show="isNumeroSelecionado(numeros)" >Apagar</button>
```

#### Problema das casas decimais

Crie uma função, `toFixed()`, semelhante a já existente no javascript nativo, porém esta reconhecerá se há casa decimais, e caso haja, irá limitá-las a duas:

```
function toFixed(number){
    number = parseFloat(number);
    if(number % 1 != 0){
        return parseFloat(number.toFixed(2));
    }else{
        return number;
    }
}
```

Assim basta aplicar isso ao final de cada função (soma e subtrair valores):

```
$scope.total = toFixed($scope.total);
```

#### Ficaria assim - EDITADO

```
function toFixed(number){
    number = parseFloat(number);
    if(number % 1 != 0){
        return parseFloat(number.toFixed(2));
    }else{
        return number;
    }
}
$scope.total = 0;
$scope.somarValores = function (numero) {
     $scope.total += parseFloat(numero);  
     $scope.total = toFixed($scope.total); 
}
$scope.subtrairValores = function () {
    $scope.numeros.forEach(function(el, i) {
        if($scope.numeros[i].selecionado){  $scope.total -= parseFloat($scope.numeros[i].valor); };
    })  
    $scope.total = toFixed($scope.total); 
}
```

## [Resultado Final - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68egLy6k/embedded/result/#Result)

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: +1 ótima resposta.

Comment: @SamirBraga, 
A sua ajuda foi muito valiosa, eu adicionei o código completo comentando algumas coisas que você falou, delete $scope.numeros, deu tudo certo, só que tenho um problema com as casas decimais, veja na imagem, será que dar para resolver o arredondamento do valor para duas casas decimais usando o ng-pattern? Eu fico muito grato por existir pessoas assim como você. Imensamente agradecido.

Comment: @Techies, sim, realmente uma ótima resposta, mais veja na imagem, estou com um problema no arredondamento do valor para duas casas decimais.

Comment: @itasouza, isso pode ser resolvido facilmente, caso queira posso editar a resposta com uma sugestão

Comment: @SamirBraga, se possível editar a sua resposta por favor. Imensamente agradecido

Comment: No caso, o ng-pattern vai fazer apenas a validação, porém ainda irá mostrar na tela as casa decimais, irei fazer uma função em javascript para reconhecer se há casa decimais e quando houver limitá-las a 2. Ok?

Comment: @itasouza, editei a resposta, veja se lhe serve.

Comment: @SamirBraga, só tenho a agradecer! , sobre formatar as casas decimais não deu muito certo, mais eu vou estudar  melhor

Comment: @SamirBraga, alterei o código completo com as últimas alterações para ficar como ajuda para outros

Comment: @itasouza, muito bom. Quanto ao problema das casas decimais, aqui funcionou direitinho, editei a pergunta extamante como usei aqui. Olhe em "Ficaria assim - EDITADO" rsrs

Comment: @SamirBraga, tudo perfeito, tudo funcionando agora! imensamente agradecido!

Comment: Código completo é final na pergunta,

Comment: @itasouza, muito bom mesmo, ficou muito feliz em ter ajudado.

Comment: @SamirBraga , Caro Samir Braga, se você tiver condições de me ajudar nesta outra questão, agradeço desde já a ajuda.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106557/como-enviar-dados-do-angularjs-para-um-backend-em-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @itasouza, crio que dessa vez não posso te ajudar, backend e  principamente asp.net não é muito comigo...rsrs