# Como enviar dados do AngularJS para um backend em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Qual seria a melhor e mais simples alternativa?

Tenho o Web Api:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Generico.Dominio;
using Generico.Aplicacao;

namespace AspNetWebApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/AspNetWebApi")]
    public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {

        //http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/consulta/JogosPorID/5
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("consulta/JogosPorID/{id:int}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage JogosPorID(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new  JogoDetalheAplicacao();
                var listar = tTabela.ListarTodos(id);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listar.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }



        //http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/cadastrar/jogo/4512/20.01/20.10/5
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("cadastrar/jogo/{nJogo}/{valor}/{total}/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Cadastro(int nJogo, decimal valor, decimal total, int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new JogoDetalheAplicacao();
                tTabela.Inseri(nJogo, valor,total,idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Cadastro realizado.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }


        //http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/deletar/jogo/4512/5
        //precisa usar o postman com opção delete formato json
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("deletar/jogo/{nJogo}/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Deletar(int nJogo, int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new JogoDetalheAplicacao();
                var resultado = tTabela.Excluir(nJogo, idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }


        //http://localhost:1608/api/ApiGuiaCidade/datahora/consulta
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("datahora/consulta")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetDataHoraServidor()
        {
            try
            {
                var dataHora = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataHora);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Tenho o Script:

```html
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var numeros = angular
    .module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http, $log) {

        var sv = this;

        var sucessoCalBack = function (response) {
            $scope.detalhes = response.data;
        };

        var erroCalBack = function (response) {
            $scope.error = response.data;
        };


        //assim funciona, passando o parametro direto 
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            params: { idusuario: 5 },
            url: 'http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/consulta/JogosPorID/5'})
             .then(sucessoCalBack,erroCalBack);
        });


        sv.getAll = function (idusuario, onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/consulta/JogosPorID/',
                params: { idusuario:idusuario }
            };
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };


            //Inser Detalhe
        sv.post = function (nJogo, valor, total, idusuario, onSuccess, onFail) {
                var config = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/cadastrar/jogo/',
                    params: { nJogo: nJogo, valor: valor, total: total, idusuario: idusuario }
                }; 
                $http(config)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        onSuccess(response.data);
                    }, function (response) {
                        onFail(response.statusText);
                    });
            };


       //Delete detalhe
        sv.delete = function (idusuario,numerojogo , onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: 'http://localhost:7630/api/AspNetWebApi/deletar/jogo/',
                params: { idusuario: idusuario, numerojogo: numerojogo }
            }
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };



})();
```

Resultado Final:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dúvidas:

1 - eu preciso fazer o Get passando um parâmetro que seria o ID do Usuário

2 – eu preciso fazer o post e delete também enviando o ID do Usuário é número do jogo

Estou disponibilizando o projeto completo, tem apenas 1 tabela (Com script já com dados), caso alguém consiga me ajudar a aprender isso, estou usando o VS 2015, agradeço.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-svO0-4L_-NZF9pWFVwV3p4Wms&usp=sharing

Answer (score 5):

### Cliente

A maneira recomendada de ser fazer isso é criando um *service* em AngularJS que será encarregado de se comunicar com o servidor, esse *service* então irá expor funções que serão utilizadas como interfaces de comunicação pelos *controllers*.

Um conceito que é necessário ter em mente é o seguinte:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╗
║ Controllers                            ║ Services                          ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╣
║ Lógicas da apresentação (view)         ║ Lógicas de negócio                ║
║----------------------------------------║-----------------------------------║
║ Coisas diretamente relacionadas à view ║ Coisas que independem da view     ║
║----------------------------------------║-----------------------------------║
║ Coisas específicas                     ║ Coisas reutilizáveis              ║
║----------------------------------------║-----------------------------------║
║ Responsável por buscar os dados no     ║ Responsável por fazer requisições ║
║ servidor, por exibir os dadoss, por    ║ ao servidor, por lógicas de       ║
║ gerenciar interações do usuário, por   ║ validação, armazenamento de dados ║ 
║ estilos e exibição de partes da UI     ║ dentro do app e reutilização de   ║
║                                        ║ lógicas de negócio                ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Fonte: Essa tabela é uma adaptação para o português de uma que pode ser encontrada no livro [AngularJS Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033486.do).

Aqui vai um exemplo de um *service* que montei para se comunicar com uma API RESTFul que gerencia produtos. Ele utiliza um *service* do próprio AngularJS chamado [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) para realizar as requisições em HTTP:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('products', products);

    products.$inject = ['$http', 'user', 'API_URL'];

    function products($http, user, API_URL) {
        var sv = this;
        var endpoint = API_URL + '/products';

        sv.getAll = function (onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: endpoint
            };
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };

        sv.getById = function (id, onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: endpoint,
                params: { id: id }
            };
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };

        sv.post = function (newProduct, onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: endpoint,
                data: newProduct
            };
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };

        sv.put = function (updatedProduct, onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'PUT',
                url: endpoint,
                params: { id: updatedProduct.id },
                data: updatedProduct
            };
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };

        sv.delete = function (id, onSuccess, onFail) {
            var config = {
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: endpoint,
                params: { id: id }
            }
            $http(config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    onSuccess(response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    onFail(response.statusText);
                });
        };
    }
})();
```

E como você faria a utilização desse *service* no *controller*? Bom, segue aqui um exemplo do *service* acima sendo utilizado:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ['$scope', 'products', 'user'];

    function MainController($scope, products, user) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.products = [];

        products.getAll(function (data) {
            vm.products = data;
        }, function (errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage);
        });

        vm.deleteProduct = function (id) {
            if (!confirm("Would you like to delete this product?")) {
                return;
            }   

            products.delete(id, function (response) {
                var productIndex = vm.products.findIndex(function (value, index, traversedObject) {
                    return value.Id === id;
                });

                if (productIndex > -1) {
                    vm.products.splice(productIndex, 1);
                }

                alert('Product successfully deleted');
            }, function (errorMessage) {
                alert(errorMessage);
            });
        };
    }
})();
```

### Servidor

O serviço em ASP.NET MVC pode ser criado através de um *action method* que retorna um [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx), segue abaixo um simples exemplo:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomeJsonData()
{
    var model = new { Name = "João", LastName = "Silva" };

    return Json(new { Data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Mas eu recomendo que você dê uma olhada no ASP.NET Web API. Diferente do ASP.NET MVC, o ASP.NET Web API é um framework desenvolvido especificamente para a criação APIs RESTFul.

Ele possui muitas facilidades que ajudam a desenvolver uma API mais rapidamente, como por exemplo a integração por padrão com o Json.NET para "serializar" objetos em JSON, dentre outras coisas.

Comment: Fique com dúvidas, então eu não consigo enviar os dados direto para o controller?, eu preciso apenas fazer um poste dos dados : numero é valor, como eu poderia fazer este servisse? agradeço

Comment: @itasouza atualizei minha resposta adicionando algumas informações sobre como os *controllers* e *services* devem ser utilizados e como utilizar o *service* do exemplo em um *controller*. Espero que assim fique mais claro para você. :)

Comment: Eu vou criar um service e prepara ele para receber os dados, assim que ficar pronto caso tenha dúvidas eu retorno a pergunta, agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda.

Comment: Eu montei o serviço, fiz os testes é ate conseguir retornar os dados, mais não conseguir seguir, veja que alterei o meu código, também postei o projeto que só tem 1 tabela, seria possível você me ajudar a fazer isso? agradeço

Comment: @itasouza Para fazer um GET você passa os dados por parâmetro utilizando a propriedade `params` no objeto de configuração do *service* `$http`, de uma olhada no meu exemplo de *service* e procure pelo método `sv.getById`. Já sobre o POST, você passa os dados utilizando a propriedade `data` no objeto de configuração do *service* `$http`, de uma olhada no meu exemplo e procure pelo método `sv.post`.

Comment: fiz os ajustes, postei o código é adicionei uma cópia no Google Drive, veja se esta correto, veja se falta alguma coisa, agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Estou subindo uma copia do projeto, o link está no final da pergunta, no google Drive, só que vai demora uns 10 minutos, está subindo é está lento hoje.

Comment: @itasouza Pelo o que vi aqui está certinho, eu só faria algumas alterações no código como perfumaria, mas da maneira que está parece estar funcionando corretamente.

Comment: @itasouza Não precisa não, acabei vendo depois que você também colocou na pergunta o código. xD

Comment: @itasouza Caso lhe interesse, esse artigo aqui é um guia de estilo para você formatar seu código em AngularJS da melhor maneira possível, de modo que fique mais fácil de fazer manutenção no futuro. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: eu ainda tenho duvidas, está ainda difícil o entendimento, por isso se possível faz ai os ajustes, eu alterei o get veja se vai funcionar quando eu enviar o parâmetro do Angular, neste caso eu vou precisar ter este projeto separado apenas para ficar recebendo os dados do angular? vou ver o artigo

Comment: Tem alguma forma de testar sv.getAll?

Comment: Bom, você pode testa-lo utilizando um botão na aplicação, aí você utiliza a *directive* `ng-click` e passa para ela a chamada de uma função do *controller*. Tipo, `ng-click="ctrl.salvarProduto()"`.

Comment: eu precisava de um exemplo mais dentro da realidade do código se possivel:
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="myController.getAll(5)">Listar Dados</button>